# Como crear un QR en RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc

Buen dia, tengo un reporte hecho en RDLC y jalo mi informacion desde un DsData, en las herramientas del reporte esta IMAGEN, arrastre una imagen y me aparece las siguientes opciones...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen qr1 es una imagen cualquier que tome del internet, pero como puedo ponerle el valor de la URL con el value de un campo por ejemplo este: =First(Fields!QR.Value, "DataSetSaldosModal") suena algo ilogico, o alguna idea por favor para poder poner QR de antemano gracias.

Comment: Tu guardas la imagen como binario dentro de la base de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para este tipos de requerimientos lo que he echo es usar el API de Códigos QR de Google

por ejemplo armo una url como esta, donde, pones tu texto en el parametro "chl":

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=TExto%20de%20Pruebas&choe=UTF-8
```

con esa se genera el código QR

puedes encontrar la documentación en este [enlace](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes?hl=es-419)

Comment: "puedes encontrar la documentación en este"  En este... que???? Me dejaste expectante!

Comment: Se me fue poner en enlace, ya lo actualicé, gracias!

Comment: Menos mal!! pensé que iba a morir con la duda !! :P